# Can't fix @BelongToMany() communication problem

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, migration

Gives errors when trying to run the code.

user.ts

```
import { BeforeCreate, BelongsToMany, Column, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

import { Task } from './task';
import { UserTask } from './usertask';

@Table
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ allowNull: true })
  role: string;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Task, () => UserTask)
  tasks: Task[];

  @BeforeCreate
  static async hashPassword(user: User) {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(
      user.password,
      Number(process.env.SALT_ROUNDS),
    );
  }
}
```

task.ts

```
import { Column, Table, Model, BelongsToMany } from 'sequelize-typescript';

import { User } from './user';
import { UserTask } from './usertask';

@Table
export class Task extends Model<Task> {
  @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: false })
  name : string;

  @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: false })
  content : string;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => UserTask)
  users: User[];
}
```

usertask.ts

```
import { Column, ForeignKey, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

import { Task } from './task';
import { User } from './user';

@Table
export class UserTask extends Model {
  @ForeignKey(() => Task)
  @Column
  taskId: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  userId: number; 

  @Column({
    defaultValue: 1,
  })
  status: number;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Migrations:

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        unique: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      role: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  },
};

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Tasks', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      content: {
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Tasks');
  },
};
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('UserTasks', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      taskId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Tasks',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { 
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      status: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('UserTasks');
  }
};
```

Error:
UserTask has not been defined

```
Error: UserTask has not been defined
    at Sequelize.model (C:\Users\Playi\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Универ\ProjectUnivercity\univer\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:4quelquelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize.js:30:26)
    at BelongsToManyAssociation.getThroughOptions (C:\Users\Playi\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Универ\ProjectUnivercity\univer\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\associations\belongs-to-many\belongs-to-many-association.js:33:49)
```

If I comment out the connection in the user everything will work.
These are the lines:

```
@BelongsToMany(() => Task, () => UserTask)
  tasks: Task[];
```